# Stability of the ODE with periodic coefficients / Periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE system

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\dot x = -2x - z \cos t, \\ 
\dot y = x \sin t - y, \\ 
\dot z = -4z + \sin^2 t.
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
I am asked to:

1) Examine stability of this system

2) Determine if the system has $2\pi$-periodic solutions.

Since we usually refer to monodromy operator in cases like this, I noticed that, given a homogeneous system 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\dot x = -2x - z \cos t, \\ 
\dot y = x \sin t - y, \\ 
\dot z = -4z.
\end{array}
\right. 
$$ $z$ is an eigenvector with an eigenvalue $-4$, hence one of the monodromy eigenvalues is $e^{-4\pi}$. Then, since we can explicitly calculate $z$ from the 3rd equation, substituting it into 1st equation and considering the homogeneous part
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\dot x = -2x, \\ 
\dot y = x \sin t - y.
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
we observe that $x$ is an eigenvector with an eigenvalue $-2$, so $e^{-2 \pi} $ is the second monodromy eigenvalue. Replacing $x$ in the 2nd equation with its explicit expression, we get the third monodromy eigenvalue: $e^{-\pi}$. Since all the monodromy eigenvalues are less than 1 (by absolute value), system is asymptotically stable.

That is my solution on the first problem. Is it correct?

And how can I solve the second problem?